# Best way in php to find most similar strings?

Tags: php, matching, levenshtein-distance

Hell,

PHP has a lot of string functions like levenshtein, similar_text and soundex that can compare strings for similarity.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Which is the best for accuracy and performance?

Comment: I think this would be better suited as a Community Wiki

Comment: Without knowing too much about the different functions' implementation details, I have a gut feeling that you can't aim for both accuracy and performance. They are probably kind of inversely proportional.

Comment: @András You may well be able to answer which is better for performance, and which is better for accuracy however.

Comment: I know someone who wanted something a bit like this. They ended invoking a command line diff tool!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

similar_text has a complexity O(max(n,m)**3) and levenshtein a complexity of O(m*n), where n and m are the lengths of the strings, so levenshtein should be much faster. Both are 100% accurate, in that they give the same output for the same input, but the outputs for each function will differ. If you are using a different measure of accuracy, you'll have to create your own comparison function.

Comment: Actually, just checked on php and their complexity is different: "The complexity of the (levenshtein) algorithm is O(m*n), where n and m are the length of str1 and str2 (rather good when compared to similar_text(), which is O(max(n,m)**3), but still expensive). "

Comment: It depends a lot on what is different to you. I found `similar_text` to better suit my case. `levenshtein` will return more similarity if strings are of the same length.

For example: 'marco blabla' compared to 'rob blabla' gave 81.8% (similar_text) and 4 (levenshtein). And 'jan blabla' compared to 'rob blabla' gave 70% (similar_text) and 3 (levenshtein). So `levenshtein` thinks the last ones is more similar and `similar_text` thinks the first ones are more similar.

Answer (score 1):

You did not describe your use-case, but in many cases when we speak about natural language words are more important than characters, so both `similar_text()` and `levenshtein()` may give less meaningful results at a very high calculation cost.

For example to search articles with similar title in a database using those above with few thousand articles can clog up a server easily.

What I usually do is to write a simple function that accepts two strings, splits them at whitespaces into arrays and count the intersection to get a low-cpu-cost more natural matching score.

With few improvements it can really excel in several use-cases, such as quickly give recommended articles in a blog filtered from other content.

Improvements I usually implement:

- lowercase the strings
- give score by the matched element's length raised to the power of 2, considering the fact that longer strings are harder to match also they tend to indicate a more meaningful similarity between topics
- throw out common words that only modulate meaning before comparison - this is language specific, in English it may be a list such as: was, were, no, not, than, then, here, there etc.
- throw out all punctuation marks from the strings before comparison
- when dealing with synthetic languages which may attach various endings enrich the array of words with variants of words truncated by the most common suffix lengths before selecting their intersection

It is not perfect, but for comparison this algo processes cca. 5000 thousand blog posts and gives 3 very good similar article with no noticable performance impact while on the same server doing the same with levenshtein takes good 10-15 seconds which is obviously not acceptable for a webpage loading.

And if you need difference instead of similarity, the score can be reciprocated or you could just use the non-matching terms after an array diff instead of the count of matching terms after an array intersect.