# check string for variations of a given string

Tags: php, email

I have a document form in which e-mail-adresses of telephone interviews are manually registered. Unfortunately very frequently there are some typos in the e-mail part in front of the @-sign.
Can someone help me how I can check the address for such typos?

Some examples:

```
Name                   Correct mail       Wrong mail
----------------------------------------------------
David Miller           david.miller@      david.miler@      <- l missing
Juliette Smith         juliettesmith@     juleittesmith@    <- ei instead of ie
Peter White            pete.white@         
Peter Miller           peter.miller@      peder.miller@     <- d instead of t
```

Is there a function to determine the number of differences / degree of difference between two strings in PHP?

My idea is that I could check separately whether the firstname and then the lastname appear in the e-mail-adress with a tolerance of a maximum of 2 characters. It is better to be on the safe side, so there should also be a warning in the "Peter White" example: Even though the "r" is missing the e-mail-address might still be correct.

Unfortunately I cannot simply take a function that gives me the number of characters differing between two strings: The problem is that peder.miller@ ("d" instead of "t") and "peder.thisismylonglastname@" have a very different number of character differences even though the typo is the same. Actually I am looking for a way to check whether any variation of "peter" (peter, aeter, beter, pe1er, pete. etc.) appears in the address.

Actually, `levenshtein()` and `similar_text()` do not really help me:

I can easilly calculate the levenshtein value or value of similar_text. But this value will highly depend on the length of the address itself. I just want to know wheter any variation of the first name or last name appears in the e-mail-address (before the @-sign). For "Peter" this might be "*eter", "p_ter", "pe_er", "pet_r", "pete*", "__ter", "p __er", "pe __ r", "pet __" etc.

Comment: I think `similar_text` is what you are looking for: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: using levenshtein distance to match words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757251/php-using-levenshtein-distance-to-match-words)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947698/best-way-in-php-to-find-most-similar-strings

Comment: Just be very careful about using this. It's going to be super-easy to detect false positives.